# Assign function signature to type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Let's say I have a function:

```
function registerEvent(event: Event, handler: HandlerSignature);
```

and these are the respective types:

```
enum Event {
  EventOne,
  EventTwo
}

type HandlerSignature = (...args: any[]) => void;
```

Now every event could have a different function signature, for example:

```
function handler1(foo: number, bar: string);
function handler2(foo: string);
```

What I'd like to achieve is that I can call the `registerEvent` function, specify the first arg (event) and let TypeScript detect which signature corresponds with this event, i.e. for intellisense and to prevent users from assigning wrong signatures to an event.

I thought about creating a map where I assign the different signatures to the enum values, but I can't really use that as type, can I? Even if I used a mapped type I'd have to create a variable to assign all the events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd lean toward function overloading:

```typescript
enum Events {
  EventOne,
  EventTwo
}

type HandlerSignature = (...args: any[]) => void;

function registerEvent(event: Events.EventOne, handler: (foo: number, bar: string) => void): void;
function registerEvent(event: Events.EventTwo, handler: (foo: number) => void): void;
function registerEvent(event: Events, handler: HandlerSignature):void {
    // ...implementation
}

function handler1(foo: number, bar: string) {}
function handler2(foo: string) {}

registerEvent(Events.EventOne, handler1); // Works
registerEvent(Events.EventOne, handler2); // Error as desired, wrong type for callback
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAogbqALgZygbwFBVgkiDyIwANFjkgCoDuA9hgL4YaICeADsFABICGIAJgBtgAJwDKASwDmIHojAjOAXigAKAHSaeIqcgBcUPiwDaAXQCUUJQD4ocGhP4BuJgDMwIAMaIJNEFEUpCWREUXgkVWBcRANwvGR1OIIiYigACz4hUQNVVxoaA3AIACNRVOLtAxCRCRApSxs7B35zA3tHF3cvHz8A4CCQsOjI6NjohKTqGlSMgWERHLyCqCLSkQbbdpa25s6Pb19-QODQkSSRpDGkZBnM+YNeOdFJGTkFYFat9DJsAHpfqCadQSCBsYQQJByQ4MNz7Hr+WZZEQARly+UKkDW5UqUGqtXq6EYXQOvUR8wATGjlni6pY0IwMMdBmdhkkJtFCCR0ndRMjzE4oP8oAB1GgiADWyEZ-ROQwibMSHJS3KeInJ-MFAJgIhEYsMqH4wGQEkU-FSVF1dSgrA4UDyIignh4gkEFU84qAA)

*(Note I changed `Event` to `Events`; `Event` is a pre-existing global and type in the browser environment and Node.js)*

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a very elegant approach, I didn't even know that overloading works like this.

Comment: @Blade - My pleasure. I should note that it only works this way when the event is a constant value. If you had a variable of type `Events`, then of course TypeScript doesn't know what specific value it will have at runtime so it'll expect a handler that can handle either call.